# Is it legit to link to a deleted question via web.archive.org (or any similar service)?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, broken-link

After searching for some information, I found a question, where the [<sup><sub>(current)</sub></sup> accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747914/alternative-to-knockout-js/6747933#6747933) has a link to a deleted question. [Someone with more than 10k reputation fixed this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6747933/revisions) by putting a link to the cached version on web.archive.org...

Is it legit to bypass the deletion by linking a deleted question with a web cache (either Google or Web Archives)?

Comment: Not just someone with >10k, it was the original poster of the answer, in response to someone else editing it out. (Just fyi)

Comment: I was told once that links to web cache are blocked by some corporate firewalls

Answer (score 8):

And that's exactly why link-only answers are such a bad idea/practice. The correct thing to do here is to take the (relevant) content from the deleted answer and put it in the currently visible answer. That way the information survives on its own rather than being dependent on the existence of another site.

---

Having said that, this particular thread is terrible it deserves to be removed. We do not want list recommendation questions and we certainly don't want link-only opinion based answers to list recommendation questions. This thread is the perfect proof for why.

Comment: Indeed, the question does not respect StackOverflow guidelines but my question was for any *good* question/answer on S.O which can reference to another answer for reference (and not a "link-only" answer).

Comment: Well, don't just link to external information without at least quoting the gist of it in the answer - applies to every answer. :)

Comment: @deceze - What is external information? Is any other question/answer in SO also external? I have seen that usually (or maybe even always) links to other SO questions/answers are used without quoting.

Comment: If the "answer" solely consists of a link to another SO answer, it's hardly an answer at all and will/should be deleted. If the answer can stand on its own merits and merely links to further tangentially relevant information elsewhere which is not essential to understanding the answer itself, that's fine. You can't quote the entire internet, at some point you'll just have to link elsewhere if you want to point to "more information".