# How can I see a deleted question with less than 10k rep?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

Some time ago, I bookmarked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256103/some-good-examples-of-restful-web-apis). At that time, I used resources/answers from it to design an API. Now I want to upgrade my API.

Because the question was deleted, I can't access it anymore. I don't even know why it was deleted. This is worrisome.

Can someone show me the contents of the question? Does it deserve a reopen vote?

Comment: You can´t see it.

Comment: "I don't know why it was deleted" - it is a list question. It doesn't conform to current quality standards and a moderator deleted it.

Comment: I was surprised it was deleted, not only closed. List questions are not a good fit for SO, but I really don't know where else I could find a curated list with comments/scores. These questions tend to be reopened and closed for the same good reasons. The fact that [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262596/is-it-legit-to-link-to-a-deleted-question-via-web-archive-org-or-any-similar-se) happens is a bit troubling.

Comment: Maybe there could be a space for questions which would be lists by design, it would avoid the same questions being opened by newcomers and closed by moderators over and over. Someone said in one of the list questions I found that the question should be community wiki?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only see a deleted question in these cases:

- It is your own
- You are a moderator on the site
- You have +10k on the site

The Internet Archive may have the question and answers. It might not.

Comment: The Internet Archive has a snapshot from about a year ago: http://web.archive.org/web/20130725070425/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256103/some-good-examples-of-restful-web-apis

Comment: It's troubling to delete stuff(not close) that is non offensive and non spam in a knowledge website. I felt bad being a low rep user and not being able to see(not edit) content :(

Comment: @alaeri - Keeping content that the community has decided is not helpful for the long term health of the site is actively harmful. How so? It encourages **current** users to as such questions (if that's open, surely it's OK).

Comment: one could argue that deleted questions are more harmful as users do not see the similar question as closed :)

Comment: The user should be able to find deleted questions at Stack Printer, I'll go take a look...

Comment: Nope, can't find it at [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted) `:/`

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that the content helped you, and it can be useful for others as well, you can write a *good question and answer* based on your experience and post it on Stack Overflow.

Please keep in mind:

- Rewrite it to fit in Q&A format as per the rules of the site.
- The question should elaborate the problem clearly. So that other users can understand the problem and post more answers.
- The answer should be clear and good. If it helped you, then there is fair chance that it will help others in future.
- Post the answer along with the question, at the same time using the checkbox for self answer.

You do not need any additional reputation for this. And it will add to the knowledge base which we are building.

You can read : [What's the right way to self-answer if other answers assisted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262210/whats-the-right-way-to-self-answer-if-other-answers-assisted)

Comment: For a list type question: You're thinking that one answerer should take the responsibility to compile some of the best answers/links and add some comments to why he thinks this is the best list?
We would lose the ability to upvote/downvote/comment on one link specifically. There would be only very long comment thread. What would be the incentive for others to post their answer to be added to the list? From your link, the curator of the accepted answer would mention other answers, and upvote them?

Comment: This is a very interesting approach and seems better than to close these questions. SO could put a warning for moderators and answerers to do this instead of closing the question.

Comment: Im sorry, I was not talking anymore about this specific question but about questions which ask a list type answer that tend to be closed and asked again regularly.

Comment: Yes, that will be best, as all the contributions and attributions will stay. If that's not possible, the least that can be done at present is if OP posts a good question and answer, there is fair chance others will post answers, and a new tree will grow from the seed. Something is better than nothing.

Comment: I will look further in meta to see if this discussion already happened and what were the conclusions.