# How come I can see a deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I still don't have a 10K rep (I'm getting there), but for some reason I'm able to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785598/php-function-to-write-value-to-mysql-on-page-load/), deleted a short while ago.

I searched and found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262608/how-can-i-see-a-deleted-question-with-less-than-10k-rep) - But this is not my question, I'm not a moderator, and I don't have the sweet 10K rep privileges at the moment.

I did answered this question however and deleted my answer (That was upvoted once) because I realized it's better to let the user debug their own code, so I VTC as " a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of deleted question]

Did I win a special prize or something?

Comment: Well, I think exactly the fact that you answered is why you can see it. I don't have 10k on meta.SE and I can see a deleted answer of mine under a deleted question.

Comment: @M.A.R. But I don't think it should be this way - Take a look at the other question I linked to - I'm not with any of the criterias listed there

Comment: @M.A.R. Apparently you were right :) But this is something new I didn't knew anything about

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have answered the question, so you can see it.

This was a change made a few months ago - giving people a chance to see their answers even if the question they were on was deleted.